# Problem wth JSON argument when using Aspera Fastex Command line interface

Tags: json, cmd, command-line-interface

In windows, in the command line, I am not able to send packages with Aspera Fastex Command Line Interface, here are two examples of the commands I tried:

```
aspera faspex send -t "Send-test" -r "*Attachment" --source 1 -f y:\folder-test --metadata=  { "Ticket ID":"test name" }

aspera faspex send -t "Send-test" -r "*Attachment" --source 1 -f y:\folder-test --metadata= {"metadata_fields" : {"Ticket ID": "test name"}}
```

The output is always ‘JSON Exception’, How should be parsed the JSON argument?

```
JSON Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting the parameter and doubling the QUOTATION MARK characters inside the parameter.

```
"--metadata={""metadata_fields"" : {""Ticket ID"": ""test name""}}"
```

Or possibly:

```
--metadata= "{""metadata_fields"" : {""Ticket ID"": ""test name""}}"
--metadata "{""metadata_fields"" : {""Ticket ID"": ""test name""}}"
```

Comment: Finally I made it works doubling the quotation mark chars: --metadata="{""Ticket ID"":""test name""}"

Comment: If this answer is correct, please use the check mark to indicate to others that it is correct. That is how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

The actual parsing of the command line depends on the operating system and shell used...

the command line tool ("aspera") will use an array of string as input, this array of string is either parsed by the invoking shell, or system call, or language runtime (C/C++)

In you case, I guess you are starting on windows, so the double quote thing solves it.
Refer to:
https://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm
http://www.windowsinspired.com/understanding-the-command-line-string-and-arguments-received-by-a-windows-program/

concerning the aspera command line itself, you may consider:
https://github.com/IBM/aspera-cli